# Typescript - define interface keys based on a type

Tags: typescript

I have the following type and interface:

```js
import { FC } from 'react';

export type RuleType =
  | 'userId'
  | 'userSegment'
  | 'userBasketItem'
  | 'userPurchases'
  | 'lastPurchaseDate'
  | 'userPurchasedItem'
  | 'userPurchasedGroup'
  | 'allUsers';

interface RuleInputs {
  userId: FC;
  userSegment: FC;
  userBasketItem: FC;
  userPurchases: FC;
  lastPurchaseDate: FC;
  userPurchasedItem: FC;
  userPurchasedGroup: FC;
  allUsers: FC;
}
```

Instead of typing every key for `RuleInputs` by hand I would like it to be added dynamically when new values are added to the `RuleType` union. Is there a way to do this using Typescript or do I need to update both types when `RuleType` changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)** to achieve your desired behavior:

```
import { FC } from 'react';

export type RuleType =
  | 'userId'
  | 'userSegment'
  | 'userBasketItem'
  | 'userPurchases'
  | 'lastPurchaseDate'
  | 'userPurchasedItem'
  | 'userPurchasedGroup'
  | 'allUsers';

type RuleInputs = {
  [R in RuleType] : FC
}
```

I also whant to show an example, where the type is used directly as an type annotation.
Maybe you dont need an explicit named type/interface when its just used for one variable.

```
const anyVar: { [P in RuleType] : FC } = { /** content here */ }
```

---

**Advanced ussage**

Filter out some `RuleType`

```
// filter out 'userId' and 'userEegment'
type RuleInputs = {
  [R in RuleType] : R extends 'userId' | 'userSegment' ? never : FC
}
```

Assign different types to specific `RuleType`

```
type RuleInputs = {
  [R in RuleType] : R extends 'userId' | 'userSegment' ? AnyType : FC
}
```

Mix different conditions for specific `RuleType`

```
type RuleInputs = {
  [R in RuleType] : 
    R extends 'userId' | 'userSegment' ? never :
    R extends 'userBasketItem' ? any : 
    FC
}
```